# Rails 6: How can I run validations on an ActiveStorage item outside of the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a model `Profile` which has an attachment `image`.

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy

  has_one_attached :image
  validates :image,
            content_type: [:gif, :png, :jpg, :jpeg],
            size: { less_than: 2.megabytes , message: 'must be less than 2MB in size' }
  after_initialize :set_default_image

  has_many :gallery_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_items, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, :short_description, :slug, presence: true
  #...
```

In addition to image validation (I'm using the [active storage validation gem](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations)), `Profile` validates the presence of `name`, `short_description` and `slug`.

Since implementing this, I have a new requirement in a view. I now want to allow the user to submit an image separately from the other attributes.

I don't want to change the underlying model. As such, I want to introduce a separate controller and class to handle a form for the submission of the image alone.

I've tried two ways.

First, I had a simple class to handle this:

```
class ProfileImageFormSubmission
  def initialize(record, params)
    @params = params
    @record = record
  end

  def save
    record.update_attribute(:image, image_param)
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :params, :record

  def image_param
    params.fetch(record_param).require(:image)
  end

  def record_param
    record.class.name.underscore.to_sym
  end
end
```

It would be called in my controller like so:

```
class ProfileImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login

  def update
    @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)

    if ProfileImageFormSubmission.new(@profile, params).save
      #...
```

The problem is, that the image isn't validated and so is attached to the the profile no matter what. (I used `#update_attribute` because I wanted to skip the validations on the other attributes -- it wouldn't make sense to display an error for the name column when the field isn't presented to the user.)

I have also tried to solve the problem by running the validations outside of the model. But here, I'm struggling to understand how to integrate `ActiveStorage` with a plain old Ruby object.

```
class ProfileImageFormSubmission
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveStorage
  include ActiveStorageValidations

  attr_accessor :record, :params
  has_one_attached :image

  validates :image,
          content_type: [:gif, :png, :jpg, :jpeg],
          size: { less_than: 2.megabytes , message: 'must be less than 2MB in size' }

  def initialize(record, params)
    @params = params
    @record = record
  end

  def save
    binding.pry
    record.update_attribute(:image, image_param)

    if record.invalid?
      record.restore_attributes
      return false
    end
  end

  # This model is not backed by a table
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  private

  def image_param
    params.fetch(record_name).require(:image)
  end

  def object_name
    record.class.name.underscore.to_sym
  end
end
```

I can't even instantiate the above class as it fails with the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `has_one_attached' for ProfileImageFormSubmission:Class):
```

What's the best way to validate an active storage item seperately?

Is it possible to run validations on a single column without triggering other validation errors?

Is it at all possible to use active storage items outside of an `ApplicationRecord` model?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do it with just one model. You'll need to create a second "Image" or "Attachment" class with the active storage validation and then you'll be able to create the image first.

Even if it's probably possible to keep everything just in one model, skipping the validation will lead to data inconsistencies. Keeping it separate will ensure that every record in your DB is valid and you won't run into unexpected states (like profiles without a name, even though you're "validating" its presence).

So it would look like this:

```rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  (...)

  has_one_attached :file
  validates :file,
            content_type: [:gif, :png, :jpg, :jpeg],
            size: { less_than: 2.megabytes , message: 'must be less than 2MB in size' }

  (...)
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  (...)

  has_one :image # or belongs to

  (...)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class ProfileImageFormSubmission

  def initialize(record, params)
    @params = params
    @record = record
  end

  def save
    record.assign_attributes(image: image_param)
    record.valid?
    record.errors.to_hash.except(:image).each { |k,_| record.errors.delete(k) } # removing errors for other attributes

    return false if record.errors.any?

    record.save(validate: false)
  end
  ...
```

If a `Profile` is not mandatory for a `User`. Then you may want to move the image to `User` class instead.

Comment: I was heading in this direction. This works for me. I've made a slight change however. I've moved `record.errors.to_h.except(:image).each { |k,_| record.errors.delete(k) }` to before the conditional so that even if the image is saved successfully, there are no other errors reported. The conditional is now `record.errors.none?`. On second thoughts, it could mask meaningful errors if this class was used at the same time as `Profile`. …It might be better to strip the messages in the view/controller.

Comment: This class is only responsible for saving an image to the `Profile`, for anything else you should use `Profile` or create similar class as above if `Profile` doesn't fit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I had to build a little bridge to the model.

```rb
class ApplicantForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :applicant, :first_name, :last_name, :photo

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :photo, presence: true
  validate :format_and_size_of_photo

  def save
    if valid?
      applicant.update(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
    end
  end

  def format_and_size_of_photo
    applicant.validate
    
    errors.add(:photo, applicant.errors[:photo]) if applicant.errors[:photo].present?
  end
end
```

In the model I have the ActiveStorageValidations

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?